# How to avoid 'X' is not a constructor error in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, constructor

I'm creating a RESTApi using node and mongo and while saving data into mongo I am getting a not a constructor error. I have no clue why I am getting this.

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
})

module.exports= mongoose.model('Posts',postSchema);
```

Now, here's my route file:

```
const express= require('express');
const router= express.Router();
const userpost= require('../model/post')

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hey Thats a post')
})

router.get('/specific',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('specific post')
})

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.title)
    const Post= new userpost({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
    })
    Post.save().then(data=>{
        res.json(data);
    })
})

module.exports=router;
```

After I try to use a Post request I get a error saying userpost is not a constructor.

> TypeError: userpost is not a constructor
> at E:\docs\node\routes\posts.js:15:17

Comment: console.log(userpost) and see what comes out of it

Comment: if I am logging before the new userpost initilization,its showing empty json '{}' and if i do it after the initialization, its showing that constructor error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you creating new Schema you have to use `new` keyword.

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //attributes
})
```

[Schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition)

Comment: it worked, what was really the problem here? why new?

Comment: Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new